# Missing div tag, causing problems

Tags: css, html

This is giving me a hard time.. I've used divcounter.jhousemedia.com and it tells me that there are two div tags missing. What I don't understand is that both of these posts are exactly the same, so I'm not sure why this is happening..

Here is a post where it doesn't happen:

Here is a post where 2 div tags are missing:

On the 2nd one, the footer is floating on the top of the page, and the sidebar is on the bottom. Anyone know where or what div tag I am missing? Both are the same posts generated on the fly by wordpress so I don't understand this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your links are not opening here...

Comment: Not opening? What do you mean?

Comment: I am unable to open your site

Answer (score 1):

You're missing closing DIV tags for

`<div id="main">`

and

`<div id="wrapper">`

I ran your site through the [wc3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://ifandco.com/2011/03/21/hangover-aka-im-old-weekend/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) :

If this is a wordpress generated page, you might want to look at your post content and make sure that there aren't any extra/omitted tags.

You might also want to address the other issues mentioned in the link

Comment: I also recommend the w3c validator for such tasks.